# Regards to function() in JSP

Tags: jquery, function, jsp, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I came across a function where it's as below:

```
<script id="tmpl-grid-action" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-xs' onclick='editForm("#=Id#")'><s:message code='global.btn.edit' /></button>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' onclick='delConfirm("#=Id#")'><s:message code='global.btn.delete' /></button>
</script>
```

And Im not sure how --> delConfirm(#=Id#) works.

How is it when I clicked this button, this button when onclick will trigger the function, and the function's parameter will automatically grab the ID from related field, and I'm not sure where it grabs from, and how does that work?

Im using Kendo UI Grid.

Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [template](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview). From the documentation :

> Kendo UI Templates use a simple templating syntax called hash
>   templates. With this syntax, the # (hash) sign is used to mark areas
>   in a template that should be replaced by data when the template is
>   executed. The # character is also used to signify the beginning and
>   end of custom JavaScript code inside the template.
>
> There are three ways to use the hash syntax:
>
> 1. Render values as HTML: **#= #**.
> 2. Use HTML encoding to display values: **#: #**.
> 3. Execute arbitrary JavaScript code: **# if (true) { # ... non-script content here ... # } #**.

There is also use of [external template](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview#handle-external-templates-and-expressions) :

> It is common for templates to include expressions. Some templating
>   frameworks invent their own re-implementation of JavaScript to provide
>   expression sugar at the cost of performance, but Kendo UI templates
>   opt to allow the execution of normal JavaScript inside templates,
>   again favoring performance over expensive syntax sugar.

Example from documentation :

```
<div id="example"></div>

<script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <ul>
    # for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { #
        <li>#= myCustomFunction(data[i]) #</li>
    # } #
    </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // use a custom function inside the template. Must be defined in the global JavaScript scope
    function myCustomFunction (str) {
        return str.replace(".", " ");
    }

    //Get the external template definition using a jQuery selector
    var template = kendo.template($("#javascriptTemplate").html());

    //Create some dummy data
    var data = ["Todd.Holland", "Steve.Anglin", "Burke.Ballmer"];

    var result = template(data); //Execute the template
    $("#example").html(result); //Append the result
</script>
```

So for **your example** you should have some something this :

```
<div id="div-where-you-want-to-insert"></div>

<script id="tmpl-grid-action" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-xs' onclick='editForm("#=Id#")'><s:message code='global.btn.edit' /></button>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' onclick='delConfirm("#=Id#")'><s:message code='global.btn.delete' /></button>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var template = kendo.template($("#tmpl-grid-action").html());

    var data = {Id: "XXX"};

    var result = template(data);

    $("#div-where-you-want-to-insert").html(result);
</script>
```